# Although I am using entity framework library in my packet manager,I can not connect to entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

As you see in The image,although i am using entity framework library,I can not connect to entity framework,the error is shown in the image.[image]

Comment: Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions -Version 5.0.0-preview.6.20312.4

Comment: @LDS I did it,but my problem did not solve

Comment: Your project is not .Net Core, you choose entity-framework 6 tag but you are trying to EF Core?

Comment: Please can say whether your project is in net core or mvc or asp.net web app